# How to create an alias with multiple commands that accepts parameters in Cmder?

Tags: alias, cmder

I would like to know how to create one alias with multiple commands in Cmder, that accepts parameters and injects them into the commands.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To separate commands in a single alias `$t` would do the trick.
To retrieve all the parameters passed to an alias `$*` would do the trick.

### Examples:

- Multiple Commands: `alias serveApp=cd "C:\app" $t grunt serve`
- Parameters: `alias nav=cd $*`, usage: `nav "C:\app"`
- Combination: `alias servePath=cd $* $t grunt serve`

Comment: Didn't understand the Parameter and Combination steps. Could you explain ?

Comment: In the parameters step: the $* will be replaced with the parameter "C:\app", thus forming cd "C:\app". The combination is two commands, first the cd to parameter, and second grunt serve.

Comment: Okay, I didn't undertstood this that way. Thanks !